"Error: 'RECEIVER_EXPORTED' or 'RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED' Required After Upgrading to targetSDK 34 for Firebase FCM In-App Calls
I recently upgraded the target SDK of my app from 33 to 34. After this update, I started encountering the following error:
One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts

My AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <!-- Add the following permission on devices running Android 12.0 or later -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />-->

    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label=""
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>

Questions

How should I configure the broadcast receivers in AndroidManifest.xml to be compatible with API level 34?
Are there any additional steps needed for Firebase FCM integration to work with the new target API level?

What I Tried:
Checked Firebase Configuration: Confirmed that Firebase FCM settings and setup are correct and up to date.
Development Environment

tool: AndroidStudio
language: dart
flutter_callkeep: 0.3.4


You need to recheck all uses of registerReceiver and add a flag to mark whether or not to export starting from API 33
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);
    } else {
        context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }


Use this, I added android:exported="true":
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:exported="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
    android:exported="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
>

